# Extract some portion from line with regular expression

Tags: text-processing, grep, command, cut

I have file which consist lines like :

```
50.57.61.8 - - [04/Apr/2019:09:52:01 -0400] "GET /tracker.php?q=1&p=2 HTTP/1.1" 302 20 "-" "Rackspace Monitoring/1.1 (https://monitoring.api.rackspacecloud.com)"
50.57.61.9 - - [04/Apr/2019:09:52:01 -0400] "GET /tracker.php?q=1&p=2 HTTP/1.1" 302 20 "-" "Rackspace Monitoring/1.1 (https://monitoring.api.rackspacecloud.com)"
```

Now I want to get output like:

```
50.57.61.8 - - [04/Apr/2019:09:52:01 -0400] "GET /tracker.php?q=1&p=2 HTTP/1.1" 
50.57.61.9 - - [04/Apr/2019:09:52:01 -0400] "GET /tracker.php?q=1&p=2 HTTP/1.1"
```

How we can achieve this using linux command(grep/cut ...etc)?

Answer (score 1):

At least with that particular data<sup>(*)</sup>:

With `cut`, take the first eight space-separated fields:

```
$ cut -d' ' -f1-8 < someinputfile 
50.57.61.8 - - [04/Apr/2019:09:52:01 -0400] "GET /tracker.php?q=1&p=2 HTTP/1.1"
50.57.61.9 - - [04/Apr/2019:09:52:01 -0400] "GET /tracker.php?q=1&p=2 HTTP/1.1"
```

With `sed`, use `s///` and a regex to remove the first double quote followed by a space, and everything after it (and put the quote back):

```
$ sed -e 's/" .*/"/' < someinputfile 
50.57.61.8 - - [04/Apr/2019:09:52:01 -0400] "GET /tracker.php?q=1&p=2 HTTP/1.1"
50.57.61.9 - - [04/Apr/2019:09:52:01 -0400] "GET /tracker.php?q=1&p=2 HTTP/1.1"
```

<sub>(* that is to say, that looks like Apache's log file, but I can't remember all variants of the exact format, so I may be making assumptions.)</sub>

Comment: < input means input file right?

Comment: @groy, yeah, that's standard input redirection. In `< foo`, the input comes from a file called `foo`. `sed` and `cut` could take the filename from the command line, too, so you could also use `cut -d' ' -f1-8 inputfilename` (without the `<`). There are minor differences between the two variants, use whichever you like.

Comment: suppose I have read a file upto 333 line number using 'grep' command, later some more line added then I want to use grep command to read from 334 to end of file. what should be the command?

Comment: @groy We don't really do follow-up questions in comments. If you need to ask a new question, then do so as a new question (possibly referring with a link to this one if needed).

Comment: Yes above file contend is from apache log