# Use grep command to read a file from specific line number to end of file

Tags: linux, grep, command, cut

Suppose I have a file which is getting appended in every seconds/minutes. At first time I have read whole file and stored the last line number(eg: last_line_numer was : 2000) later I want to read file using 'grep' command to look for a pattern from line number 2001 to end of file. How we can achieve this?

First time I ran below command:

```
grep 'tracker.php' apache.log | cut -d' ' -f1-8
```

Now I want to ran above command with specific line number in grep param.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tail to output the file from line number 2001 and pipe the result to your command:

```
<apache.log tail +2001 | grep 'tracker.php' | cut -d' ' -f1-8
```

Comment: When I use command like:

grep -n 'tracker.php' apache.log | cut -d' ' -f1-8

then it gives line number from apache.log file like:

141007:50.57.61.8 - - [04/Apr/2019:09:52:01 -0400] "GET /tracker.php?q=1&p=2 HTTP/1.1"
141008:50.57.61.9 - - [04/Apr/2019:09:52:01 -0400] "GET /tracker.php?q=1&p=2 HTTP/1.1"

but when I use:

<apache.log tail +141009 |  grep -n 'tracker.php' | cut -d' ' -f1-8

then it give line number 1,2,3 but not 141009, 141010, 141011.

How can I get this?

Comment: `cat -n apache.log | tail +2001 | grep -o '.*tracker.php[^"]*"'`if we take the logfile from your [other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/517128/extract-some-portion-from-line-with-regular-expression)

Comment: I am not able to use this command by storing value in variable , here is ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56066661/how-to-store-value-in-variable-having-special-character-and-linux-command-in-php

What can be issue here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
awk 'NR<2001 {next} /tracker.php/ {print NR, $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8}' apache.log
```

or

```
awk 'NR<2001 {next} /tracker.php/ {print NR, $0}' apache.log | cut -d' ' -f1-9
```

which will also display the original line numbers of the matching lines in the file.

Comment: Or `awk 'NR>2000&&/tracker.php/ {NF=8; print NR,$0}'`

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
sed '1,2000d; /tracker\.php/!d' | cut -d ' ' -f-8
```

That is, discard lines 1 through to 2000 (inclusively), and then also discard any line not containing the string `tracker.php`.  Send the rest of the lines through `cut`.